# Implementing a binary search

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to implement a binary search; it takes an ordered list, takes the mid value, compares it to the target value, then sub-lists either above or below the mid value until the target is found or is missing from the list. However, for some reason, I always get 'None' returned unless the midpoint is the target. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

```
def bisect(list,target):


    print list
    split= list[len(list)//2]
    print "Split value : " + str(split)  

    if target==split: 
        return "target" 

    elif target<split:
        bisect(list[:split],target) 

    elif target>split:
        bisect(list[(split):],target)

a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]       
print bisect(a,2)

Output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Split value : 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Split value : 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Split value : 3
[1, 2, 3]
Split value : 2
None
```

It looks like the last compare between split and the target value isn't occurring?

Comment: why not use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module?

Comment: @FredrikPihl or at least - look at how the `bisect` module implements its functions for comparison

Comment: As a side note: Calling your list `list` is confusing, and means you can't use the type/constructor of the same name within your function.

Comment: @abarnert true I'm not using the type so it's causing problems, but the way I did it is bad form. I will change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. When you recurse by calling `bisect`, you still need to *return* the value of the call by doing `return bisect(list[:split],target)`.
2. `split` is an element of `list`, not an index, so `list[:split]` won't do what you think.  Use `list[:len(list)//2]` instead, and likewise change `list[split:]` to `list[len(list)//2:]`.

Comment: It would be nicer to do `splitpoint = len(list)//2`, then do `split = list[splitpoint]` and use `list[:splitpoint]` and `list[splitpoint:]`, instead of repeating the same expression 3 times. But otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @abarnert `list[:splitpoint]` and `list[splitpoint+1:]`. Omitting the +1 can lead to infinite recursion.